# Spring Property value NULL

Tags: spring-boot

```
@Autowired
public JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;

@Autowired
public StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;


@Autowired
public JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

@Autowired
public DataSource dataSource;

@Autowired
TaskletStep taskletStep;

@Value("${spring.firstName}")
public String firstName

  
  String selectABC  ="SELECT * FROM WHERE ABAACD = '" + firstName+
```

Hello above property value is null inside select statement,but i can see the value after@Value in firstName variable in debug mode.

whats missing here?

Comment: initialise the selectABC inside a constructor

Answer (score 0):

Spring will inject properties sometime after the object is constructed. For your variable `selectABC` you are setting it before constructor call, and objects default to null.

You need to use `@PostConstruct` annotation to guarantee Spring has finished initializing the bean for you.

```
String selectABC;

@PostConstruct
public void init() {
  selectABC  ="SELECT * FROM WHERE ABAACD = '" + firstName + "'";
}
```

Another option would be to append the constant portion directly inside the `@Value` annotation:

```
@Value("SELECT * FROM WHERE ABAACD = '${spring.firstName}'")
String selectABC;
```